# How to get a specific machine type for ML Engine online prediction?

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

Is there an option to request a faster node for **online prediction** in ML Engine?

For example, when training I can configure any of these machines for my job:

> standard,
>   large_model,
>   complex_model_s,
>   complex_model_m,
>   complex_model_l,
>   standard_gpu,
>   complex_model_m_gpu, 
>   complex_model_l_gpu,
>   standard_p100, 
>   complex_model_m_p100

See description of available clusters and machines for **training** [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview#machine_type_table) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-gpus)

I am struggling to find if it is possible to control what kind of machine runs my online prediction.

Comment: Could you post the content of the link, so it is understandable from your question without link?

Comment: edited question to include the essence of the links

Answer (score 0):

We are currently adding that capability and will let you know when it's publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

ML Engine offers 4-core instance type in addition to the default serving instance type for online prediction. However the feature is still at alpha stage and it will only be available to a selected list of accounts who opted in as "Trusted Testers". Please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com if you need help to setup prediction service with faster node.